# How to set the UsbInterface (isochronous) manually for a USB device (Kinect)

Tags: usb, kinect, libusb, openni, printer-control-language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set USB transfer type manually for a device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467192/set-usb-transfer-type-manually-for-a-device)

I use openni to interact with my Kinect on a ARM-Board (Pandaboard ES). To get openni running on this Platform it needed some tweaks, one of them is to set the UsbInterface manually (in the GlobalDefaults.ini provided by the openni-driver).

Now I want to use PCL to grab some frames but PCL doesn't work. I believe that pcl tries to set the USB-Interface on its own and tries to bypass the GlobalDefaults.ini, respectively does not use my manually set USB-Interface.

My question is if I can set the option for the USB-Interface to isochronous globaly for a device? Do I need to change the driver or the Kernel?

Would be great to get you help...
Thank you